# How do I remove all of the files that have to do with TeamViewer in /etc/apt/sources.list.d?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

I tried to install TeamViewer and have gotten this far (below) so I would like to delete it all and update my OS from 19.04 to 20.04 before proceeding with TeamViewer.

My second question; if allowed, is how did they all get there? I think because perhaps I tried to install 2 different versions...

I am still very new at this and am struggling through learning as I go.  Thank you.

```
root@linuxtanya:/etc# apt-get source teamviewer
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:5
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:6
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:4
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
root@linuxtanya:/etc#
```

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) It's intended upgrade path was to 19.10, however since 19.10 is now also EOL the intended upgrade path is also gone.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  A re-install maybe your best option as a *newbie*, and I suggest sticking to LTS or *long-term-support* releases if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months (19.04 meant 2019-April release with 9 months supported life; it's upgrade path was possible until 19.10 reached EOL)

Comment: You haven't said if server/desktop or what type of release, *Team Viewer* implies desktop to me, so you could backup, then do an upgrade via re-install (*something-else*, use existing partitions without format & it'll note your packages, wipe system directories, install new system, add back packages your added if available in Ubuntu repositories then ask to reboot). It won't touch user files unless you format; but server apps can have *conf* & like files lost where stored in system directories (desktop apps don't do that).

Comment: @guiverc...I'm going go about this an entirely different route and if I need to ask a new question I will be glad to...(1) backup 19.04 onto external. (2) create a new partition (3)  have the hard drive from my old  Windows Vista, install on new partition (4) delete 19.04 and install 20.04 in its place (I have 20.04 ISO backed up on the external hard drive).Is this doable or am I too ambitious as a newbie?

Comment: @guiverc...I am doing all of this on an HP4540S laptop that was given to me with only Ubuntu 19.04 (single boot). I know this version is outdated and 20.04 is an LTS and that's where I want to be.

Comment: I don't understand your windows reference.  You can just install Ubuntu 20.04 over your existing system and achieve the upgrade (as I tried to describe last comment; it takes a fraction of the time of a *release-upgrade* too). You could also backup your data, clean install, then restore the data you want to return, but I see little need of that. Anything you're doing in windows I'd just do using the *live* Ubuntu install media.  (I don't see why you want to use *new* partition)

Comment: @guiverc...Windows reference is that I have my hard drive from my old PC and it runs Windows Vista. It is my understanding that I can run both OS on one machine; but the best way to do that is to install Ubuntu after Windows. I am wondering if I can create partition and download the Vista to new partition; then install 20.04 ISO over old version on first (existing) partition? And I don't have a clue as to what I'm doing; a month ago I would have sworn this was all Greek.

Comment: Yes you can dual boot, installing both ways works of course; window first just saves a likely *fix* step which is why it's suggested.  I'm not a person to guide with windows though (I've not supported it in ~six years & off-topic here), but yes what you're doing does make ~sense now;

Comment: @guiverc...I apologize for off topic but I am not versed in any of this but I am very stubborn so off I go (I realize this entire thread went off topic but ultimately this is all I want to accomplish so why take baby steps (original question)when I can just jump in and drown (that's a joke) trying to achieve the end goal! Thank you so much for your help!